# Angular - Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-loop, angularjs-digest

I´m currently working on a project where I have to do multiple post request from a view. The problem in my case is, that I always get an infinite $digest loop. Here is my current code:

js-file:

```
$scope.foo = function(param) {
   var deffered = $q.defer();

   $http.post('ASDASD.php', {string : param})
     .then(function(data) {
       deffered.resolve(data);
       $scope.$apply();
    }
  );

  return deffered.promise;
};

$scope.bar = function(param) {
  $scope.foo(param).then(function(result) {
    return result;
  });
};
```

view:

```
<div ng-controller='asdfCtrl'>
   {{bar('asdf')}}
    ...
   {{bar('jkl')}}
</div>
```

As you can see I used promises, watcher and $scope.$apply, but there´s still an infinite loop.

Is there a way to make sure, that the function bar (and corresponding foo) is just called once?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `bar('asdf')` and wouldn't display anything anyway - you're not returning anything from the function. And even if you did return the `$scope.foo(param)`, all you'd get is the promise object returned by your `$scope.foo()`. And it makes no sense to make http requests every time the digest loop is called anyway, that's a LOT of requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a more efficient way to solve this!

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to make requests each time the digest cycle runs. Change your code like this instead:

JS:

```
$scope.results = {};

$scope.bar = function(param) {
    $scope.foo(param).then(function(result) {
        $scope.results[param] = result;
    });
};

$scope.bar('asdf');
$scope.bar('jkl');
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    {{results['asdf']}}
    ...
    {{results['jkl']}}
</div>
```

In addition, remove the `$scope.$apply()` from your `$scope.foo` function, it's unneeded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a more efficient way to solve this!

Comment: @c_reil Mind sharing the 'more efficient' way? I'm having exactly the same issue as you had.